# Filter/Ignore JUnit Testmethods listed in File during execution

Tags: java, junit, junit4, test-runner, junit-runner

**Given:**

- A package with Testclasses. Each test class has hundreds of test methods. Some of those test classes use their own runner.
- A file with strings of that form: absolut.path.Testclass.testMethod

**Should:**

- Run only those test methods that are described in the text file, including their setup and tear down.
- Run them with the runner defined in their Testclass (not optional)

**What has been tried**

- CustomSuiteRunner + CustomRunner as Delegate

  - A TopLevel-Suite of all the Suite has been created that uses the CustomSuiteRunner
  - The CustomSuiteRunner collects all the Runners of the included Tests
  - The CustomSuiteRunner wrapes each Runner in the CustomRunner
  - The CustomRunner delegates all Calls but "isIgnored()" to the encapsulated Runner.
  - Problem: To execute single Methods, the CustomRunner expected all encapsulated runners to be a ParentRunner. But some Runners like Mockitos Runner are plain Runners. How to access their Methods I don't know.

**Question**
How can I achieve the execution of a group of test methods from several test classes?
If Runners are not the best option, I would be interested in alternatives, also.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html#Running_a_Set_of_Methods_in_a_Single_Test_Class)?

Comment: The project is quite old and not using maven.

Comment: I checked further into JUnit: Its quite easy by writing a custom runner BUT I could not solve the problem of running tests that define Runners themselfs.
My Idea was the following:
- create a custom Suite Runner and a suite that uses this runner and , a Custom Runner.
- The suite runner collects all the defined runners of the contained tests and encapsulates them inside the custom runner. This custom runner delegates all its calls but the "isIgnored" to the encapsulated runner.
Probelm was that some runners do not expose their Methods (runChild()) but only a "run()".